# Can't get a post with too many comments using Rfacebook library

Tags: r, facebook, rfacebook

I am receiveing an error message when I try to get a post with too many comments (or maybe likes) using Rfacebook library.
It works just fine in post with less comments tough.

Is it a problem in Rfacebook library or is it a restriction from facebook itself?

Here's the code and the the error I'm seeing:

insider <- getPage(page = "thisisinsidertravel",token = fboauth)

getPost(insider$id[1], fboauth)

**Error in while (n.l < n.likes & length(content$data) > 0 & !is.null(url <- content$paging$`next`)) { : 
  argument is of length zero**

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.